# My query didn't return any result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a select query on table and the result is more then 15000 lines, when i execute it with pdo, it didn't return any result

Is there any solution to return the result with my script.

NB : in `phpMyAdmin`, the query return the desired result

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname="namedb";charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from table");
$sth->execute();
var_dump($data = $sth->fetchAll());
```

Comment: maybe you are not connected or a 100 other reasons

Comment: You should post your real code (apart from your password...) as `table` is not going to work in phpMyAdmin either. And add error handling; have PDO throw exceptions for example.

Comment: 15,000 rows! Maybe you have blown the memory limit, or the execution time limit. All these and many other possibilities can be checked by ___Looking at your error log___ or using `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of each script you are debugging

Comment: Or dare I say it, checking the status's of each line of PDO code. They all return one, or setting PDO to throw exceptions